# How to print a string to the terminal in x86-64 assembly (NASM) without syscall?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am new to assembly, and want to first try to get an intuitive feel for how printing a string to the terminal would work, without going through the operating system abstraction (Linux or OSX).

(Editor's note: the accepted answer only covers Linux.  x86-64 MacOS uses a similar system-calling convention but different call numbers.)

**tl;dr** How do you write to stdout (print to the terminal) in x86-64 assembly with NASM on OSX, at the lowest level possible (i.e. without syscall)? How is BareMetal OS doing this?

Most examples show something like [this](http://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/nasmexamples/):

```
global start

section .text
start:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, message
  mov rdx, 13
  syscall

  mov eax, 60
  xor rdi, rdi
  syscall

message:
  db "Hello world", 10
```

In there, they are using `syscall` to print the string, which is [relying on the operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592937/where-are-the-system-codes-coming-from-in-x86-64-assembly#comment43609669_27592971).  I am not looking for that, but for how to write a string to stdout directly, at the lowest level possible.

There is this exokernel project, [BareMetal OS](https://github.com/ReturnInfinity/BareMetal-OS) that I think is doing this. Though since I am new to assembly, I don't know enough yet to figure out how they accomplish this. From what it seems though, the two important files are:

- [syscalls/screen.asm](https://github.com/ReturnInfinity/BareMetal-OS/blob/master/os/syscalls/screen.asm)
- [syscalls/string.asm](https://github.com/ReturnInfinity/BareMetal-OS/blob/master/os/syscalls/string.asm)

It seems the relevant code to print is this (extracted from those two files):

```
;
; Display text in terminal.
;
;  IN:  RSI = message location (zero-terminated string)
; OUT:  All registers preserved
;

os_output:
  push rcx

  call os_string_length
  call os_output_chars
  
  pop rcx
  ret

; 
; Displays text.
;
;  IN:  RSI = message location (an ASCII string, not zero-terminated)
; RCX = number of chars to print
; OUT:  All registers preserved
;

os_output_chars:
  push rdi
  push rsi
  push rcx
  push rax

  cld ; Clear the direction flag.. we want to increment through the string
  mov ah, 0x07 ; Store the attribute into AH so STOSW can be used later on

;
; Return length of a string.
;
;  IN:  RSI = string location
; OUT:  RCX = length (not including the NULL terminator)
;
; All other registers preserved
;

os_string_length:
  push rdi
  push rax

  xor ecx, ecx
  xor eax, eax
  mov rdi, rsi
  not rcx
  cld
  repne scasb ; compare byte at RDI to value in AL
  not rcx
  dec rcx

  pop rax
  pop rdi
  ret
```

But that doesn't look complete to me (though I wouldn't know yet since I'm new).

So my question is, along the lines of that BareMetal OS snippet, how do you write to stdout (print to the terminal) in x86-64 assembly with NASM on OSX?

Comment: So you think code in `syscalls` doesn't involve syscalls?  And how do you expect to do any kind of I/O by circumventing the OS (management of which is one of its jobs)?

Comment: Hmm, there is no reference at all to `syscall` or `int 0x80` in the whole repo, which is why I'm wondering how they do it.

Comment: stdout *is* an OS abstraction.  I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Haha, forgive me I am new to all this so don't know the distinctions too well. I am just looking for the lowest-level, correct way to write to the terminal in assembly. If stdout _is_ an OS abstraction, then how do you create stdout in assembly? (so then I can use that to print to the terminal).

Comment: Try `mov byte [0xb8000], 'X'`. That's essentially what `os_output_chars` does.

Comment: Bare Metal OS does it by writing bytes to video memory. Linux won't let you do that.

Comment: @FrankKotler: only on IBM compatible computers, in certain video modes, with certain (not *too* old) video cards...

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking BareMetal OS. I missed that Lance wanted to do it on OSX. Hack the kernel, I guess.

Comment: gallileo specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571379/intel-galileo-bare-metal-uart

Comment: Related: printing integers: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good exercise. You will use `syscall` (you cannot access `stdout` otherwise), but you can do a "bare-metal" write without any external library providing the output routine (like calling `printf`). As an example of the basic "bare-metal" write to `stdout` in x86_64, I put together a example without any internal or system function calls:

```
section .data
    string1 db  0xa, "  Hello StackOverflow!!!", 0xa, 0xa, 0

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        ; calculate the length of string
        mov     rdi, string1        ; string1 to destination index
        xor     rcx, rcx            ; zero rcx
        not     rcx                 ; set rcx = -1
        xor     al,al               ; zero the al register (initialize to NUL)
        cld                         ; clear the direction flag
        repnz   scasb               ; get the string length (dec rcx through NUL)
        not     rcx                 ; rev all bits of negative results in absolute value
        dec     rcx                 ; -1 to skip the null-terminator, rcx contains length
        mov     rdx, rcx            ; put length in rdx
        ; write string to stdout
        mov     rsi, string1        ; string1 to source index
        mov     rax, 1              ; set write to command
        mov     rdi,rax             ; set destination index to rax (stdout)
        syscall                     ; call kernel

        ; exit 
        xor     rdi,rdi             ; zero rdi (rdi hold return value)
        mov     rax, 0x3c           ; set syscall number to 60 (0x3c hex)
        syscall                     ; call kernel

; Compile/Link
;
; nasm -f elf64 -o hello-stack_64.o hello-stack_64.asm
; ld  -o hello-stack_64 hello-stack_64.o
```

**output:**

```
$ ./hello-stack_64

  Hello StackOverflow!!!
```

For general use, I split the process into two parts **(1)** getting the length and **(2)** writing to `stdout`. Below the `strprn` function will write any string to `stdout`. It calls `strsz` to get the length while preserving the destination index on the stack. This reduces the task of writing a string to `stdout` and prevents a lot of repitition in your code.

```
; szstr computes the lenght of a string.
; rdi - string address
; rdx - contains string length (returned)
section .text
        strsz:
                xor     rcx, rcx                ; zero rcx
                not     rcx                     ; set rcx = -1 (uses bitwise id: ~x = -x-1)
                xor     al,al                   ; zero the al register (initialize to NUL)
                cld                             ; clear the direction flag
                repnz scasb                     ; get the string length (dec rcx through NUL)
                not     rcx                     ; rev all bits of negative -> absolute value
                dec     rcx                     ; -1 to skip the null-term, rcx contains length
                mov     rdx, rcx                ; size returned in rdx, ready to call write
                ret

; strprn writes a string to the file descriptor.
; rdi - string address
; rdx - contains string length
section .text
        strprn:
                push    rdi                     ; push string address onto stack
                call    strsz                   ; call strsz to get length
                pop     rsi                     ; pop string to rsi (source index)
                mov     rax, 0x1                ; put write/stdout number in rax (both 1)
                mov     rdi, rax                ; set destination index to rax (stdout)
                syscall                         ; call kernel
                ret
```

To further automate general output to `stdout` NASM macros provide a convenient solution. Example `strn` (short for `string_n`). It takes two arguments, the addresses of the string, and the number of characters to write:

```
%macro  strn    2
        mov     rax, 1
        mov     rdi, 1
        mov     rsi, %1
        mov     rdx, %2
        syscall
%endmacro
```

Useful for indents, newlines or writing complete strings. You could generalize further by passing 3 arguments including the destination for `rdi`.

Comment: Hardly bare metal, but the lowest level possible on a bona fide protected mode OS such as Linux.